# JAVA: Chunked Tranfer over Jersey

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, chunked-encoding

I have a web service running which will be used by a client side mobile application. One of the services is to return an array of JSON objects (over 1000 objects), each object of considerable size. The whole computation on the server side takes some time, and that is not a good user experience. So i was hoping to send the data in chunks, say 10 objects per chunk, such that this data occupies the screen and when he scrolls, or when the data is ready, the screen is filled with the newly acquired data from the latest chunk received.

I use a Jersey framework and send a Java `Response` object as the return object. Is it possible to achieve the chunked-transfer in this scenario?. The code is something like this.

```
@Path("/doSomething")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response doSomething() {

    List<Object> myObj = getMyObj();
    /* getMyObj returns a list of Objects, each object of considerable size
    * the whole computation of getMyObj takes some time
    */
    return Response.ok(myObj).build();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scenario sounds like [server push](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology).

You could try to use [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Getting-Started-with-The-Atmosphere-Framework-and-WebSocket) framework with your Jersey service to achieve your goal.

Comment: Yes, something similar to a server push, initiated by a request from the client.  
Is it possible to achieve this without much change on the client side.?

Comment: I am afraid that some changes are definitely necessary. Server push is quite different paradigm than classic request-response pattern.